# Is returning the intermediate value in a recursive function a quirk of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

UPDATE:
Let me clarify what exactly is so confusing about this.
If I add a print statement like such:

```
    def recur(lis, json, target):
        if lis[0] == target:
            print(json[tagert])
            return json[target]
        else:
            recur(lis[1:], json[lis[0]], target)
```

my print statement will display the expected value of the JSON. I don't know how else to phrase this. Given that the line preceding the return statement gives the result I expect (without the return statement in the else) why is the return statement in the else necessary?

And for those of you that insist on downvoting this, I've looked at the multiple times the question about a missing return statement was asked. What's never been answered in any of those is WHY the return is necessary. Downvote me all you want but at least understand that you're downvoting a good question. I thought this community was maturing but obviously not.

---

So I've looked at several questions with the same title as mine and I still don't quite understand why this is the case.

If I have a recursive function like this:

```
def recur(lis, json, target):
    if lis[0] == target:
        return json[target]
    else:
        return recur(lis[1:], json[lis[0]], target)
```

I get my return value as expected.

But if I don't return the in the else statement, I get a None:

```
def recur(lis, json, target):
    if lis[0] == target:
        return json[target]
    else:
        recur(lis[1:], json[lis[0]], target)
```

```
>>> final_json = recur(my_list, my_json, 'ID')
>>> print(final_json)   
None
```

Is this specific to Python? I'm a bit rusty but I seem to remember languages like Haskell handling this more elegantly where, I believe, I don't need to return the value of the recursive call. Which makes more sense to me - I don't need all the intermediate values since I'm passing my function all the values it needs at each level of the stack. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you don't return anything explicitly from a function, it returns `None`. Some languages may differ in that respect, for example by returning the last evaluated expression.

Comment: You did not `return` the `recur(..)` call, so that means Python implictly returns `None`

Comment: Right but shouldn't the json be changing with each iteration of the function? I could be wrong but I'm *pretty* sure I don't need to return the intermediate values in other languages.

Comment: I understand what is happening - I'm asking if this is unique to python.

Comment: I am not too familiar with other languages, but this to me seems elegant. the intermediate function calls are going via the "else" step, and so the function effectively are not returning anything. A function that doesnt explictly return something, returns a None.

Comment: @Ramy - of course you do ("return the intermediate values", I mean). Even in Haskell, where there won't be an explicit `return` statement (because `return` in Haskell means something completely different), you'll still be passing the value through from the recursive call.

Comment: "I don't need all the intermediate values" What does this have to do with intermediate values? The recursive call returns the result. If your function calls itself recursively, gets the result from the recursive call, and does not return that result, then no result is returned.

Comment: You don't need an explicit return in Haskell because a Haskell function is a single expression, not a series of independent statements. You neither need to nor *can* specify a return value other than what the body evaluates to.

Comment: Just trying to be funny here: "Question: I don't understand why in English language it's called a 'pineapple', I have seen in all other languages it is called 'Ananas'" :)))
But with all seriousness, `return` and `print` are two different things -- one sends the value to `stdio` another pops it from the stack

Comment: So does this mean stdio is out of sync with the stack of something. This is one of those things I used to "know" when I programmed more but never fully made sense to me.

Comment: Why do you write `return json[target]` and not just `json[target]`? Why use `return` to return a valuer in one place and not the other? Basically all languages that use statements instead of the superior expressions needs `return` while the expression languages will use it's tail expression value as "return". Eg. i Python were like that you could omit `return` entirely.

Comment: "So does this mean stdio is out of sync with the stack of something" You could say that? stdio is a globally-accessible set of file streams, it'll print anything you send to it from anywhere regardless of the stack. `return`, on the other hand, just sends a value to the caller (which might be a recursive function), and if that caller ignores the return value, that value is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> final_json = recur(my_list, my_json, 'ID')
>>> print(final_json)   
None
```

> if I don't return the in the else statement, I get a None … I don't need all the intermediate values since I'm passing my function all the values it needs at each level of the stack. What am I missing here?

In your function call `final_json = recur(...)` you are stating that `final_json` is whatever `recur` *returns*.

If this is your implementation:

```
def recur(lis, json, target):                # line 1
    if lis[0] == target:                     # line 2
        print(json[tagert])                  # line 3
        return json[target]                  # line 4
    else:                                    # line 5
        recur(lis[1:], json[lis[0]], target) # line 6

recur(myArg1, myArg2, myArg3)                # line 7
```

Then consider exactly what happens if you call `recur(someLis, someJson, someTarget)` where `lis[0]` does NOT equal `target`.

In a pseudo-stack-trace:

```
RECUR CALL A
├─ A condition fails (line #2)
├─ A calls `recur` (l#6)
│    └─ RECUR CALL B
│       ├─ B condition fails (#2)
│       ├─ B calls `recur` (#6)
│       │    └─ RECUR CALL C
│       │       ├─ C condition passes (#2)
│       │       ├─ C prints answer (#3)
│       │       └─ C returns answer to B (#4)
│       ├─ B receives answer from C (#6)
│       └─ B returns `None` (because you didn't use `return`) (#6)
├─ A receives `None` from B (#6)
└─ A returns `None` (because you didn't use `return`) (#6)
```

Unless your outermost `recur` call happens to be on a base case (passing the condition `if lis[0]...`), the relevant line is line 6, where you have no `return` keyword.

Yes, you calculated the eventual answer on lines 3 & 4.

Yes, you `return` the answer on line 4.

But that `return` is for the call on line 6! Not the top-level call (line 7).

So you end up back at line 6, having calculated the answer you wanted and… you do nothing with it. You don't `return` it. It goes nowhere.

Eventually the stack unwinds to the top level call (line 7), which receives the default Python return value (`None`), which was the result of the last line of the function that ran (line 6), because that line had no `return` statement.

The issue isn't that Haskell "doesn't need to return the intermediate calls." It's actually the exact opposite; Haskell *automatically returns its function bodies*. There is no explicit `return` keyword in Haskell<sup>1</sup> because you are ALWAYS returning something implicitly, you just don't need to remember to type it yourself.

Here is an equivalent example:

```
def ret5 ():
    return 5

def example ():
    return ret5()

def final ():
    example()
```

If you call `result = final()`, then `result` will clearly be `None`, right? It doesn't matter that `final` called `example`, which `return`ed the answer you wanted. Since `final` didn't `return` the result of `example`, the top-level output is still `None`, even though you did "reach" the answer at some point during program execution.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is unfortunately a function in Haskell *named* `return` which has nothing to do with returning values from functions. It's a lamentable name choice which was presumably selected to make `do`-notation look more imperative. I prefer the identical function `pure` for this reason.

Comment: Can you expand on "Unless your outermost recursive call is the base case (if lis[0]...), the relevant line is line 6, where you have no return keyword." What would this function look like if my "outermost recursive call is the base case"?

Comment: @Ramy if the top-level function call happens to be on a base case, then: 1) the condition passes (line 2); 2) you print the answer (line 3); 3) you return the answer (line 4); you store the output in in a variable assignment (line 7). Line 6 never comes into play.

Also, I added a pseudo stack-trace in ASCII diagram form to illustrate better what's going on, hopefully it clicks for you.

Answer (score 5):

Best way I can think of to demonstrate this is to compare a very simple recursive recursive function, in a few different languages. The function I've chosen will compute the factorial of an integer. (A non-negative one, and for simplicity I won't attempt to perform any validation to stop the function blowing up if presented with a negative integer, or a float, or something stupid.)

Firstly, in Python:

```
def factorial(n):
    if (n == 0):
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

So here you have the "intermediate value returned", which seems to be what you're claiming seems to be unique to Python. (Of course you're not returning the result of the recursive call itself, but a simple operation performed on it - but that doesn't change the situation, unless I've *totally* misunderstood. You're still returning the value, in order to do something with this "intermediate result".)

So lets have a look at how you would do the same in Javascript. (Yes, there are more elegant ways to do this, in both languages, but I'm trying to keep things simple and strictly comparable.)

```
function factorial(n) {
    if (n == 0) {
       return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

I hope you'll agree that, putting aside trivial differences in basic syntax, the JS version is identical to the Python one above. In particular, both do that "return the intermediate value" thing.

I could write exactly the same thing in PHP, or (although I'm not so familiar with those languages) I think in C/C++/C#/Java, and it would again be very much the same.

Now if we finally come to Haskell, which is really a radically different type of language from all the above, let's look at how one might define the same function:

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n
    | n==0 = 1
    | otherwise = n * factorial (n-1)
```

Yes, there's no explicit return statement here. But that's only because Haskell functions are "pure" functions that must *always* result in a value, so instead of having an explicit statement to tell you what that value would be, at the end of some more complex code, you just define what its result is on each possible input.

Of course, you can and often do define functions more abstractly, in "point free" style using composition and other higher-order operations - this is one of the benefits of functional programming. But at the end of the day, in Haskell a function is ultimately defined in terms of what output it results in for a given input - this is actually fundamental, it's what the word "function" means in mathematics, and what it also means in purely functional languages. (As opposed to a mere "procedure", a reusable block of code that may or may not result in a value, as in most procedural languages like JS, Python and the rest.)

So in other words, the above *still* "returns the intermediate value". The `=` sign in the final line of the example does the work of the `return` statement in other languages.

So I apologise if I've gone on for too long about a really simple topic - I'm just still quite unsure as to where your confusion lies. But I hope this has helped you overcome it.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtful response. I'm not sure if it quite clarifies my query though. I've updated the question slightly.

Comment: Also, in your example of the factorial function, you're using the function call in the actual result - so here I would expect the return value to be "necessary" on the "intermediate calls".

Comment: @Ramy thanks for the clarification, although I'm afraid I'm still unsure exactly what you're asking. I see you voted for a different answer, so are you satisfied with that one or do you still need further explanation? As for your comment above on my answer - you're still "using the function call in the actual result" in your example. You need that `return` to pass the result to the code that called the function - whatever operation (or none) that you do on this doesn't change that. And I repeat that there is nothing remotely unique to Python about any of this.

Comment: I think this is making sense. The psuedo stack was what helped me most. The fact that the calculation was still happening but then not getting returning to the higher level stacks is the problem. Which, again, I used to intuitively understand that but apparently have forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to understand if we take the recursion out of the picture. Here's a similar construct:

```
def funcA(lis, json, target):
    return json[target]

def funcB(lis, json, target):
    return funcA(lis[1:], json[lis[0]], target)

>>> final_json = funcB(my_list, my_json, 'ID')
>>> print(final_json)
```

Here, we can follow the execution path:

- We call `funcB` and pass it some arguments.
- `funcB`, in turn, calls `funcA` and passes that some arguments.
- `funcA` returns a value back to `funcB`.
- That value in turn is returned by `funcB`.
- The value `funcB` returns is assigned to `final_json`.

Now, your question is, why does it stop working if we redefine `funcB` as:

```
def funcB(lis, json, target):
    funcA(lis[1:], json[lis[0]], target)
```

With this redefinition, and everything else the same, the execution path is more like:

- We call `funcB` and pass it some arguments.
- `funcB`, in turn, calls `funcA` and passes that some arguments.
- `funcA` returns a value back to `funcB`.
- That value is ignored by `funcB`.
- `funcB` ends without returning a value, so by default it returns `None`.
- The value `funcB` returns is assigned to `final_json`.

Because `funcB` never explicitly returns the value it gets from `funcA`, it returns `None` by default.

---

Since a recursive function is simply a function that calls itself, its behavior is no different from a function that calls a different function.

Here is your function:

```
    def recur(lis, json, target):
        if lis[0] == target:
            return json[target]
        else:
            return recur(lis[1:], json[lis[0]], target)

>>> final_json = funcB(my_list, my_json, 'ID')
>>> print(final_json)
```

Let's go through the same process as above, assuming it will recurse one time:

- We call `recur` and pass it some arguments.
- `recur`, in turn, calls `recur` again and passes some arguments.
- The second call to `recur` returns a value back to the first call.
- The first call to `recur` takes that value and returns it to us.
- The value the first call to `recur` returns is assigned to `final_json`.

If we remove the `return`, though:

```
    def recur(lis, json, target):
        if lis[0] == target:
            return json[target]
        else:
            recur(lis[1:], json[lis[0]], target)
```

- We call `recur` and pass it some arguments.
- `recur`, in turn, calls `recur` again and passes some arguments.
- The second call to `recur` returns a value back to the first call.
- The first call to `recur` takes that value and ignores it.
- The first call to `recur` ends without returning a value, so by default it returns `None`.
- The value the first call to `recur` returns is assigned to `final_json`.

Again, since the first call to `recur` never explicitly returns the result it gets from the second call to `recur`, it returns `None` by default.

---

> UPDATE: Let me clarify what exactly is so confusing about this. If I add a print statement like such:
>
> ```
> def recur(lis, json, target):
>     if lis[0] == target:
>         print(json[tagert])
>         return json[target]
>     else:
>         recur(lis[1:], json[lis[0]], target)
> ```
>
> my print statement will display the expected value of the JSON. I don't know how else to phrase this. Given that the line preceding the return statement gives the result I expect (without the return statement in the else) why is the return statement in the else necessary?

`print` is global, it writes to stdout without regard for function depth or stack frames. On the other hand, `return` exists on the function level, and only affects the value returned by a single function call. If that function call does nothing with the return value of the function it calls, that value is lost.

---

> Is this specific to Python? I'm a bit rusty but I seem to remember languages like Haskell handling this more elegantly where, I believe, I don't need to return the value of the recursive call.

Haskell functions define exactly one value; there's no need for an explicit `return` because the entire body of the function is in an implicit one. Other languages, such as the Lisp family, always return the value of the last line in the block, so an explicit `return` in this case is also unnecessary.

Note that in both of these cases, *both* of your `return` statements would be missing, not just the second one; this is about `return`s in general, and has nothing to do with recursive calls.

Python, and most other mainstream languages, require an explicit `return`, if you want to return any useful value.

Comment: I actually think this is the best answer - particularly regarding how `print` works differently from `return`. I'm surprised no-one upvoted it before I did.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to Python; it's specific to all C-like and C-adjacent languages (perhaps all imperative languages), and, weighted by popularity, Haskell is the odd one out.  In C, C++, Python, Perl, PHP, etc., a statement of the form `return expression` returns the given expression from the function, while just `expression` evaluates the expression and throws it away without returning it.  It's only in more functional languages like Haskell and Scheme, where a function definition tends to only have one statement, that the "return" is implicit.

Comment: So you're saying that if you're used to more functional languages this would seem weird. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramy In more functional languages like Haskell you still have to return it. You can't just ignore the return value of the recursive call.

Comment: There are also languages like Perl, where the return value of a function is the value of the last expression or statement to be executed, whether or not that involves the `return` keyword. (`sub add { $_[0] + $_[1] }` is a function that returns the sum of its first two arguments.) It has nothing to do with whether a language is functional or not.

Comment: And then there's Pascal, where the return value of a function is whatever value was last assigned to the name of the function: `function add(x, y: int): int; begin; add := x + y; end;`.  No `return` statement, but you still need to make an explicit statement of what a function returns.